# CSC : error CS0009: Metadata file '.....\v8-x64.dll' could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild

We got this error on the Jenkins server after we updated our target framework from .NET v4.5.1 to v4.5.2:

Up in the build output we have also warnings like:

> (GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) ->    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1097,5):
>   warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. To resolve this,
>   install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or
>   retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you
>   have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be
>   resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in
>   place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be
>   correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

When we try to remove `ClearScriptV8-32.dll`, `ClearScriptV8-64.dll`, `v8-ia32.dll`, `v8-x64.dll` it is compiling with no problem but unfortunately as we use them in the solution the site is not loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing on Jenkins server .NET v.4.5.2 (link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642)) resolved the problem.**

However **if the SDK installer gives you info that v4.5.2 cannot be installed** because newer version is already present you can just copy paste the whole from another machine where it is present to c\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2

**More info:**
The problem was that on the Jenkins server we didn't had .NET v4.5.2 but we had .NET v.4.6.
As v.4.6 is claimed to be compatible with 4.5.2 msbuild is using it and giving the warning that was mentioned in the question and at the end CSC  was failing to open v8 Dlls.